# Bootstrap Grid Horizontal alignment and collapse

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-grid

I'm completely new to learn bootstrap grid and my guide has mainly been using website guides and tailoring them to this example.

The expected output is supposed to look like this when fullscreen:
Expected-FullSize
[image]

and like this when collapsed to a smaller size:
Expected-Collapse
[image]

My main problem is trying to get the "Aside" and "Section" parts to stack on top of each other inside the "Article" part. I can't even get it to line up in a row with the "article" part anymore. The other details I'll work out on my own, but this part I've been struggling with for awhile.

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: black;
font-size: 2em; 
text-align: center;

}

.header {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav {
  background-color: khaki;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.article {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;

}

.aside {
  background-color: goldenrod;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;

}

.section {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;

}

.footer {
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;

}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle-Test2.css" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="header">Header</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="nav">Nav</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
            <div class="article">Article</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
            <div class="aside">Aside</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
            <div class="section">Section</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="footer">Footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did quite a bit with your code and I'll just post it back to you and I'll try to explain as many changes as I can remember :) 
I wouldn't call myself an expert with bootstrap either. So these are fun to do.

First, I noticed that `<link href=` wasn't working in the head. 
So, I changed that to bootstrap CDN and the latest version
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Be sure to match the Javascript from the same source if you want to use collapsable navigation or carousels or something like that later on...

Next, I changed the grid to look more like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
           <div class="header">Header</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
           <div class="navigation-bar">Nav</div>
      </div>


 </div>
 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm mbody">
                <div class="article">Article</div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm mbody">
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="aside">Aside</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="section">Section</div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
           <div class="footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Really, what we're wanting is two rows inside of a single column 
These changes got us close to what we want. 
The next thing was to give all of your inner div's 100% width

```
body {
 background-color: black;
 font-size: 2em; 
 text-align: center;

}
.mbody {
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
}

.header {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%; 
}

.navigation-bar {
 background-color: khaki;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%; 
}

.article {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%; 


}

.aside {
  background-color: goldenrod;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%; 

}

.section {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%; 

}

.footer {
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%; 

}
```

Notice that finally, I changed the "nav" class to "navigation-bar" so your styling will apply, since "nav" is a predefined class in bootstrap already and overrides your styling. 
Then I added the "mbody" class to the two columns and set the margins and padding to 0 to make everything fit together with no space on the left or right.

My result is looking like what you posted in the two pictures above. Hope this is helpful. :)

Comment: Thanks helped a lot! Just one question. Do you know how to make the "collapse" where it goes from stacked in the article section to their own row based on the size of the screen? I know I can use @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {...} in my CSS sheet so once the screen is less than 800 px it collapses into its own row, but not sure what to put in it since its bootstrap in order to make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's grid works in such a way that if you don't need it to change when resizing your browser, you can set just one size and will take care of the rest. col-md-12 should work just fine for you all the way down.

To solve your primary question, check out nested items: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting

Comment: The example uses bootstrap 3. Your answer points to an unsupported version of bootstrap

Comment: Oops! Good call, just updated the URL: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting